# how to enter multiple data into one column

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, many-to-many, dotnetnuke

I have 3 different tables in my c# asp.net dotnetnuke app

**Order**
PK_OrderID,
Info,
NumOfItems,
Total

**Customer**
PK_CustomerID
Name,
LastName,
Username,
Password

**OrderItem**
PK_OrderItemID
FK_Order_ID
FK_Customer_ID

I also have a form where i enter data. I have a button which dynamically creates more textboxes, so user can enter new article.

I want to know, how to enter multiple data into database.

Let's say my order looks like this:

**Order** Book, 1, 39.99€

**Order** Book, 2, 50€

Now, this is **1** order from 1 user, and it should be stored under **1** id, not multiple.

**This is how i enter my data**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="info0" class="form-control" runat="server" style="background:#fff"></asp:TextBox><br />

<asp:TextBox ID="numOfItems0" class="form-control" runat="server" style="background:#fff"></asp:TextBox><br />

<asp:TextBox ID="total0" class="form-control" runat="server" style="background:#fff"></asp:TextBox><br />
```

**This is how i load new buttons**

```
for (int i = 1; i< 5; i++)
{
tb1.ID = "info" + i.ToString();
tb1.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
tb1.Attributes.Add("class", "form-control");
tb2.ID = "numOfItems" + i.ToString();
tb2.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
tb2.Attributes.Add("class", "form-control");
tb3.ID = "total" + i.ToString();
tb3.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
tb3.Attributes.Add("class", "form-control");
ph1.Controls.Add(tb1);
ph1.Controls.Add(tb2);
ph1.Controls.Add(tb3);
}
```

**this is how i enter data into database**

```
PortalModuleBase user = new PortalModuleBase();

        Order newOrd = new Order();

        bazaDBDataContext db = new bazaDBDataContext();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            List<string> listOfItems = new List<string>();
            listOfItems.Add(info0.Text);
            string res = Request.Form["dnn$ctr416$Order$inputInfo" + i];
            listOfItems.Add(res);

            for (int j = 0; j < listOfItems.Count; j++)
            {
                string val = listOfItems[j];
                newOrd.Info = val;
            }
        }
```

I think i need to read and enter data in a way like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM OrderItem oi
INNER JOIN customers c ON c_customer_id = c.o_order_id
WHERE oi.order_id = X
```

but i just can't make it work in code.

Help me please, i'm desperate!

Comment: One order should have one orderid, and one row in order table. But several rows in the orderitem table, same orderid, but different item id's,

Comment: yes that's exactly what i want to achieve, but i have no idea how to do it @jarlh . don't even know if im entering data correctly...

Comment: Move customerid column from orderitems to orders. (Always same customer for a whole order, isn't it?)

Comment: yes one customer for one order. but store can have multiple customers @jarlh

Comment: And a customer can have ordered from several stores. (There are no stores mentioned above.)

Comment: no it's just one store. one customer can add multiple items to his order. meaning he can buy 5 books, and all i have to be stored in same order (one id)...later after he finishes his order...he can ofcourse create another order, but that order will have another id... @jarlh

Comment: meaning i would like to store multiple items in one order, and later display all those items under order ID @jarlh

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from above scenario 
First you need to insert primary data in Order table and return the OrderID then pass this OrderID in ListOfItems.

By this orderID will be unique for  multiple order items

```
    Order newOrd = new Order();

    bazaDBDataContext db = new bazaDBDataContext();  
    //  insert into order table
    // int OrderID = return OrderID from DB

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            List<string> listOfItems = new List<string>();
            listOfItems.Add(info0.Text);
            listOfItems.Add(OrderID);
            string res = Request.Form["dnn$ctr416$Order$inputInfo" + i];
            listOfItems.Add(res);

            for (int j = 0; j < listOfItems.Count; j++)
            {
                string val = listOfItems[j];
                newOrd.Info = val;
            }
        }
```

I hope this will help

Comment: the result is sadly the same. empty database.